# List of Services for SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: installation, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I recently installed VS2013 Preview onto a clean OS and I'm trying to figure out if SQL Server Express 2012 got installed.  Unfortunately, when I look in Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services, the only thing I see mentioning SQL is the "SQL Server VSS Writer"

**Can someone tell me what entries I should see in Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services after a successful installation of SQL Server Express?**

Ideally, both SQL Server Express and SQL Server Management Studio would have been installed on my PC when I installed VS2013 Preview but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

NOTEs:

1. I see a bunch of SQL Server Entries in Control Panel->Programs and Features but when I try to connect to [ComputerName]\SQLExpress via the SQL Editor of VS2013 Preview, I get a can't connect error.
2. If I remember correctly, a default installation of VS2010 Pro will also install a copy of SQL Sever Express, so I would *expect* a VS2013 installation to do the same

Comment: I believe VS2012 installs SQL Server Express LocalDB. So VS2013 could do the same.

Comment: Thanks!  I will have to look into what you say since I am not familiar with LocalDB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525818/vs2012-and-sql-server-express

Answer (score 0):

I just installed SQL Server 2012 Express (SSE) on the mentioned machine and now I see the following SQL related entries under Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services:

1. SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) - Running
2. SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) - Disabled
3. SQL Server Browser - Disabled
4. SQL Server VSS Writer - Running *(Was on PC Before Installing SSE 2012)*

Now I can connect to [ComputerName]\SQLExpress via the SQL Editor of VS2013 Preview; whereas before, I could not.

Please feel free to correct me if I have missed a critical service for a minimal install of SSE 2012 onto Windows 8.1 Preview.  In addition, I'm not entirely sure that the SQL Server VSS Writer Service is necessary, but I don't have time to verify that right now.